# How check private proxy with CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I need check proxy with CURL in my script, but there is error "**couldn't connect to host**".
Please see the code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'xx.xxx.xx.103:8080'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'login:pass'); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if ($data === false) 
{
    echo "Proxy is not working: ", curl_error($ch);
} 
else 
{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Thanks to all who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove port after ip and set port in given cURL option below

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'xx.xxx.xx.103'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8080');
```